# Beam pipeline - Difference over sequential fixed time windows aggregate

Tags: apache-beam

I'm stuck on the implementation of a simple pipeline. I grouped my data within a fixed time window of one hour to compute different aggregation. Now, I need now to compute the total energy consumed by meter. (See sample below)

For instance, the energy consumed by meter 'A' during from 14:00 to 15:00 is the difference between the energy reading at 15:00 and the energy reading at 14:00.

(800 mWh - 600 mWh) + (900 mWh - 800 mWh) + (1300 mWh - 900 mWh) + (1600 mWh - 1300 mWh) = 1000 mWh .

```
Meter Time Energy, mWh 
A 2019-06-01 14:00 600 
A 2019-06-01 14:15 800 
A 2019-06-01 14:30 900 
A 2019-06-01 14:45 1300 
A 2019-06-01 15:00 1600
```

Any idea how I could implement something like this? I'm using the python SDK.

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using a SlidingWindow of 1 hour and Stateful DoFn (note that states are per key and per window)? For example:

```
class Consumption(DoFn):
  first_gauge = ReadModifyWriteStateSpec('first', TupleCoder([VarIntCoder(), VarIntCoder()]))
  
  def process(self, element, initial=DoFn.StateParam(first_gauge)):
    initial_gauge = initial.read()
    if not initial_gauge:
      initial.write((element.timestamp, element.energy))
    elif element.timestamp - initial_gauge[0] == 3600:
      yield element.energy - initial_gauge[1]

gauge_events | 'window' >> WindowInto(SlidingWindow(3600, #or larger
                                                    900))
             | 'Calculate Consumption' >> beam.ParDo(Consumption())
```